# How many linearly independent solutions does a second order linear homogeneous PDE has?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

For a second order linear homogeneous differential equation $LF(x)=0$ where $L$ is a linear differential operator, there exists two linearly independent solutions $F_1(x)$ and $F_2(x)$. The general solution is $$F(x)=AF_1(x)+BF_2(x)$$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants which can be determined from two boundary conditions.

What about a second order linear homogeneous partial differential equation: $$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}=0$$ where $F(x,y)$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Does it also have two linearly independent solutions and the general solution is the linear combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function of the form $(x,y)\mapsto ax+by+c$ is a solution, so the answer is no.

By the way, you also have $(x,y)\mapsto e^x\sin(y)$, and more generally any harmonic function on the real plane is a solution.

Comment: Number of linearly independent solution is therefore infinite and there is no way to write a general solution?

Comment: Yes, because you could also take $F_a(x,y)=e^{ax}\sin(ay)$ for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.